# Meter todo en un php tengo un html y uyn php

Tags: php

Tengo 2 archivo un `php` y un `html` y quiero unir en uno solo. La teoría me la conozco pero por alguna razón no soy capaz. Le he puesto el `<form method="POST"> </form>` y en medio he metido el `html` pero da error.

```
form method="get" action="calculadora.php">
        <input type="text" name="operando1">
        <select name="operacion">
            <option value="+">+
            </option>
            <option value="-">-
            </option>
            <option value="*">*
            </option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="operando2">
        <input type="submit" value="enviar">
    </form>
<?php
    $cifra1 = $_GET['cifra1'];
    $cifra2 = $_GET['cifra2'];
    $operacion = $_GET['operacion'];
    swich($operacion)
    case1: $operacion == "+";
        $solucion = $operando1 + $operando2;
         break;
    case2:$operacion == "-";
        $solucion = $operando1 - $operando2;
         break;
    case3: $operacion == "*";
        $solucion = $operando1 * $operando2;
        break;
    }
    echo "La solución es: ".$solucion;
?>
```

La idea es unir todo en un solo .`PHP` para quitarme de follones.

Necesito una mano porque no soy capaz.

Comment: Que error te da?

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="get" action="calculadora.php">
    <input type="text" name="operando1">
    <select name="operacion">
        <option value="+">+
        </option>
        <option value="-">-
        </option>
        <option value="*">*
        </option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="operando2">
    <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>

<?php
if($_GET){
    $operando1 = $_GET['operando1'];
    $operando2 = $_GET['operando2'];
    $operacion = $_GET['operacion'];

    switch ($operacion) {
        case "+":
            $solucion = $operando1 + $operando2;
            break;
        case "-":
            $solucion = $operando1 - $operando2;
            break;
        case "*":
            $solucion = $operando1 * $operando2;
            break;
    }

    echo "La solución es: ".$solucion;
}
?>
```

Comment: Por favor, contextualiza en tu respuesta de que modo la solución planteada resuelve el problema del OP. Te invito a hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que sepas de lo que hablo.

Answer (score 1):

- Debes guardar tu archivo con extensión `.php`, así por ejemplo `index.php`.
- el código `php` lo pones antes del `html`
- En `switch` no estás abriendo la llave `{`
- En el atributo `action` debes llamar al mismo documento con `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $cifra1 = $_POST['cifra1'];
    $cifra2 = $_POST['cifra2'];
    $operacion = $_POST['operacion'];
    switch($operacion){
    case ($operacion == "+"):
        $solucion = $operando1 + $operando2;
         break;
    case ($operacion == "-"):
        $solucion = $operando1 - $operando2;
         break;
    case ($operacion == "*"):
        $solucion = $operando1 * $operando2;
        break;
    }
    echo "La solución es: ".$solucion;
  }
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="operando1">
        <select name="operacion">
            <option value="+">+
            </option>
            <option value="-">-
            </option>
            <option value="*">*
            </option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="operando2">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: da error al probar Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in C:\xampp\htdocs\examen\calculadora.php on line 7

Comment: La verdad es que no probé el código, el error que te muestra es por que tienes mal definido el `switch`... Edité la respuesta pero sigo sin probar el código. Los errores de sintaxis son muy específicos, este por ejemplo te dice que no esperaba los `:` en la línea 7.

Answer (score 0):

tienes varios errores de sintaxis

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="get" action="calculadora.php">
        <input type="text" name="operando1">
        <select name="operacion">
            <option value="+">+
            </option>
            <option value="-">-
            </option>
            <option value="*">*
            </option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="operando2">
        <input type="submit" value="enviar">
    </form>
</body>
</html>


<?php
if (!empty($_GET['operando1']) && !empty($_GET['operando2']) && !empty($_GET['operacion'])) {
    $operando1 = $_GET['operando1'];
    $operando2 = $_GET['operando2'];
    $operacion = $_GET['operacion'];

    switch ($operacion) {
        case "+":
            $solucion = $operando1 + $operando2;
            break;
        case "-":
            $solucion = $operando1 - $operando2;
            break;
        case "*":
            $solucion = $operando1 * $operando2;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    echo "La solución es: ".$solucion;
}
?>`

recuerda que debes guardar el archivo con extensión .php
```

Comment: Tal vez podrías desglosar tu respuesta un poco más, explicando los errores de @Carlos24345